# sbt scala plugin from github PR (ScalaNative) fails with value not found

Tags: git, scala, github, sbt, scala-native

If I needed to use the stable release version, I would have my project/plugins.sbt as below:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-native" % "sbt-scala-native" % "0.4.0")
```

I am trying to use a specific version (a PR to be precise) of ScalaNative for my project.

Here is my build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.4"


// Set to false or remove if you want to show stubs as linking errors
nativeLinkStubs := true

enablePlugins(ScalaNativePlugin)
```

And this is my project/plugins.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(scalaNativePlugin)
lazy val scalaNativePlugin = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native.git#v0.4.0"))
```

When I run sbt it fails with the following error log.

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.6 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_292)
[info] loading global plugins from /home/sadique/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading settings for project root from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading settings for project scala-native-build from build.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /home/sadique/.sbt/1.0/staging/5c4ed83a83573e9369a0/scala-native/project
[info] loading settings for project scala-native from build.sbt ...
[info] resolving key references (24414 settings) ...
[info] loading project definition from /home/sadique/Programming/scala/scala-native-template/sn-test-custom/project
/home/sadique/Programming/scala/scala-native-template/sn-test-custom/build.sbt:6: error: not found: value ScalaNativePlugin
enablePlugins(ScalaNativePlugin)
              ^
[error] Type error in expression
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

I have tried with both capital and small S in `scalaNativePlugin` for the variable name in plugins.sbt.

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, I might suggest building Scala Native locally, just fork github project, rebase to expected branch/PR, run sbt and use `publishLocal` command, if you want to get Scala 2.11 or 2.13 artifacts remember to switch used Scala version using `++SCALA_VERSION`, since sbt assumes Scala `2.12.x` as default one.
Version of the current build can be found in `nir/src/main/scala/scala/scalanative/nir/Versions.scala`, currently it's `0.4.1-SNAPSHOT`. You can use it in your project after creating local artifacts or adjust it.

Comment: Thanks. How/where do i specify the SCALA_VERSION ? I tried running `publishLocal SCALA_VERSION=2.13.4` but that promptly failed. Is there a file i need to edit somewhere?

Comment: `+publishLocal` seemed to do the job. It publishes for all supported versions of scala (2.11, 2.12, 2.13). 
I could also edit the scalaVersion variable but `+publishLocal` seems like a cleaner solution.